# _mm_set_epi8 - what does "set" mean?

Tags: x86, sse, simd

What does the `_mm_set_epi8` do?

I'm reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0cx8zd3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but I can't understand it, what is r0..r15?

Comment: Where did you encounter the function? Are you aware of the context of this function? I.e. did you read the documentation about SIMD instructions / SSE2?

Comment: No sorry, I encountered it casually while reading a website

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`_mm_set_epi8` is just a convenience macro which initialises a 128 bit SSE `__m128i` vector to a specified set of values (16 x 8 bit values in this case), e.g.

```
__m128i v = _mm_set_epi8(15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0);
```

will set `v` to the 128 bit value: `0x000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f`.

There are other similar macros for different vector element types, e.g. `_mm_set_epi16`, `_mm_set_epi32`, `_mm_set_ps`, etc.

(Note: the documentation you linked to in your question is not very good, but r0..r15 apparently just refer to the individual 8 bit fields within the returned vector).

Comment: According to intel docs, the parameter order of the intrinsic is big-endian: dst[127:120] := e15.  So the 128 bit value would be: 0x0f0e0d0c0b0a09080706050403020100.

Comment: Which, since intel processors are little endian, would be in memory the values: 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, ...